# Get last value of series in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have my excel sheet like this:

```
A | B
-----
0 | 2
0 | 3
0 | 4
0 | 5
0 | 6
0 | 7
1 | 8
1 | 9
1 | 10
1 | 11
1 | 12
2 | 13
2 | 14

...
```

How do I get the value of B for the last occurrence of each value in A?

The output is -

```
C | D
0 | 7
1 | 12
2 | 14
```

Is there an easy way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Is A and/or B always sorted as ascending? are they always in order? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Is the last value always the largest??

Comment: @Jaycal Yes, A and B are always sorted ascending. I've already written a python code, and I've already gotten what I need, but I wanted to know if I can do this in excel itself with a quick macro or something. Thanks if you can help :)

Comment: @Jaycal, tbh that doesn't as you can easily apply a filter to sort ascending

Comment: @t.thielemans Agreed, only reason I asked was because if it is, it can be more easily done with a formula

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you already have 0, 1, 2 etc. listed in C1 down then use this formula In D1 copied down

`=LOOKUP(C1,A:B)`

Comment: + 1 Nice one. Worth mentioning that in case it is a long list in Col A and the user doesn't have the values in Col C then he/she can always use Advanced Filter to generate those values in Col C :)

Comment: Might be worth clarifying this works because columns A/B are sorted.

Comment: @enderland Yes, column A needs to be sorted ascending for this to work (not B) - although you can amend to work with unsorted data

Answer (score 2):

Highlight the entire table.

On Data tab, in the Outline pane click the Subtotals button.

In the At change in... box, select A.

At the Use function box, select Max.

In the Add Subtotal to box make sure B has a check mark

Click OK.

Use the dashes to collapse each section.

That will avoid any programming or formulas and leave the data intact.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last value in column A use this formula:

```
=INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A), 1)
```

The following will get the last value in column B:

```
=INDEX(B:B, COUNTA(B:B), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A sample using a macro:

```
Sub LastValueInB()

VarA = Range("A1").Value
VarB = Range("B1").Value
Output = ""

For i = 1 To 10

    If Range("A" & i).Value = VarA Then
        VarB = Range("B" & i).Value
    Else
        Output = Output + VarA & VarB & vbCrLf
        VarA = Range("A" & i).Value
    End If

Next i

MsgBox Output

End Sub
```